# How to implement CBOW + hierachical softmax in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word2vec

I would like to implement CBOW + HS in Keras.

I found an example (https://github.com/nzw0301/keras-examples/blob/master/CBoW.ipynb), but its activation function seems like softmax not hierarchical softmax.

Is there any way to implement CBOW + HS in Keras?